# Slow loading, 1502 queries and large amount of data in session - see debug log

Tags: mysql, debugging, joomla, virtuemart

I've been trying to debug my site for some time now and I see that for every page the system is doing large amount of queries and data which is stored in session has reached almost a million characters that are encoded in the db.

The site is using joomla with ecommerce from virtuemart. This is way beyond normal and I have tried disabling all modules,plugins and components except Virtuemart.

Can someone please help me figure out where these queries are coming from and how to reduce them. I need to know how I can find out what is filling the session with all this information.

Check out this link and take a look at the debug log on the bottom of the page.

Thank you

Link: [My site](http://www.outfit.is/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&category_id=15&Itemid=216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like your system loads the data for each products seperately in one query. and there are a lot of products on that page.
same problem for example in magento.
thats the tradeoff if you get "too object oriented".
im afraid theres nothing much you can do about it without changing the guts of your system.
you may want to consider switching to another shop system that is more focused on performance.
[oxid](http://www.oxid-esales.com/) is good from what ive heard, and i've seen some convincing benchmarks and loading patterns.

other "higher layer" approaches to optimize your current system are

- checking whether opcode caching is doing ok
- have a local database server for selecting this stuff (maby replication from the master)
- make sure query caching is doing good and the ram allocations for your database are fine
- maby move your sessions to apc/memcached
- maby you have something like page html caching in your system